# Get values and positions to label a ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below code works well and it labels the barplot correctly, However, if I try `geom_text` for a histogram I fail since `geom_text` requires a `y`-component and a histogram's `y` component is not part of the original data.

Label an "ordinary" bar plot (`geom_bar(stat = "identity"`) works well:

```
 ggplot(csub, aes(x = Year, y = Anomaly10y, fill = pos)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
        geom_text(aes(label = Anomaly10y,vjust=1.5))
```

**My Problem**: How to get the correct `y` and `label` (indicated by `?`) for `geom_text`, to put labels on top of the histogram bars

```
ggplot(csub,aes(x = Anomaly10y)) + 
        geom_histogram() 
        geom_text(aes(label = ?, vjust = 1.5))
```

`geom_text` requires `x`, `y` and `labels`. However, `y` and `labels` are not in the original data, but generated by the `geom_histogram` function. How can I extract the necessary data to position labels on a histogram?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`geom_histogram()` is just a fancy wrapper to `stat_bin` so you can all that yourself with the bars and text that you like. Here's an example

```
#sample data
set.seed(15)
csub<-data.frame(Anomaly10y = rpois(50,5))
```

And then we plot it with

```
ggplot(csub,aes(x=Anomaly10y)) + 
    stat_bin(binwidth=1) + ylim(c(0, 12)) +  
    stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1.5)
```

to get

[image: labeled univariate ggplot2 barplot]

Comment: As a side note, adding `+ limits(x=c(0, 12))` will show the label for 10.

Comment: @tonytonov I should have done that. I went ahead and updated the example to extend the range so no labels are cut off.

Comment: Thanks, Its working, however, it is throwing a warning: "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead."

Comment: For factor histograms one needs to use  `+ stat_count(binwidth=1, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=0.25)` just if anyone has the same question for this case...

Answer (score 7):

Ok to make it aesthetically appealing here is the solution:

```
set.seed(15)
csub <- data.frame(Anomaly10y = rpois(50, 5))
```

Now Plot it

```
csub %>%
  ggplot(aes(Anomaly10y)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom='text', color='white', aes(label=..count..),
           position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

resultant plot will be

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to rotate the labels with `stat_bin()`?