# How to use stat_bin2d() to compute counts labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to build a plot, essentially identical to that which i can produce using ggplots 'stat_bin2d' layer, however instead of the counts being mapped to a variable, I want the counts associated with the bin to be displayed as a label to each bin.

I got the following solution to the equivalent 1D problem from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198896/how-to-get-data-labels-for-a-histogram-in-ggplot2)

```
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  stat_bin() +  
  stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1.5)
```

The counts for each bin are clearly labeled. However moving from the 1D to 2D case, this works,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_bin2d()
```

But this returns an error.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_bin2d() +  
  stat_bin2d(geom="text", aes(label=..count..))

Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

Comment: Take the time to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input so it's clear what your data looks like. Show your attempts thus far. Describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Appologies, i accidentally posted when i didn't mean to. Have updated!

Comment: The last comment I could find on this came from [Hadley in 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/6lx_mYJVf3w) where he basically says you can't use `stat_bin2d`, you'll have to do the summarization yourself.

Comment: @MrFlick, I think this has changed in recent versions of `ggplot2` - see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

In more recent versions of `ggplot` this is perfectly possible and works without errors.

Just be sure that you use the same arguments to both call of `stat_bin2d()`. For example, set `binwidth = 1` on both lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = 1) + 
  stat_bin2d(geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..), binwidth = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  xlim(-4, 4) +
  ylim(-4, 4) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally answered your question writing a question of my own. I figured out that stat_bin2d will work when you convert the variable you are binning from number to text, so:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))
x_t<-as.character(round(data$x,.1))
y_t<-as.character(round(data$y,.1))
x_x<-as.character(seq(-3,3),1)
y_y<-as.character(seq(-3,3),1)
data<-cbind(data,x_t,y_t)



ggplot(data, aes(x = x_t, y = y_t)) +
  geom_bin2d() + 
  stat_bin2d(geom="text", aes(label=..count..))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits =x_x) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=y_y)
```

So there you go. Unfortunately you have to set the binwidths outside of ggplot() so it isnt an ideal solution. I don't know why it works when you convert the variables to text, but there it is.

Comment: It's not necessary to perform this character conversion. Perhaps this was an appropriate workaround when this answer was originally posted, but it's not necessary in more recent versions of `ggplot`. See my answer.

Comment: Great! I'm glad they got this working. Binning outside of ggplot() wasn't the end of the world, but its much more convenient to do it within ggplot().