# ggplot geom_text annotation with variable label

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

Is it possible to annotate a ggplot figure with a "text" element indicating a feature of the data (variable)?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)    
my.mean <- mean(mtcars$mpg, na.rm=T)
my.mean <- as.name(my.mean)

gplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg))+geom_histogram()
gplot <- gplot + geom_text(aes_string(label=my.mean, y=5), size=3)
```

This produces something on the plot that looks like a succession of numbers. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Edit: this question is different since I am not trying to annotate each histogram bin with a value. The objective is to add one single text element to the plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data labels for a histogram in ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198896/how-to-get-data-labels-for-a-histogram-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @ scoa: I can't see how the question you referred to is solving this one. Please suggest an explicit solution.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right, you want to add a text to your plot which is defined by another dataset, i.e. a dataset which was not given as argument to `ggplot()`.

**Solution:** Pass this dataset directly to your `geom_text` function using `data=...` to use it.

```
library(ggplot2) library(datasets)
my.mean <- mean(mtcars$mpg, na.rm=T)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
        geom_histogram() + 
        geom_text(data=data.frame(my.mean=my.mean), aes(y=5, x=my.mean, label=my.mean), size=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

it should work like this:

```
gplot <- gplot + geom_text(aes(15, 5, label="some random text"))
gplot
```

with the numbers you can specify the location within your grid.

Comment: @ vano: I am trying to pass the value of `my.mean` to be printed on the plot instead of `some text`

Comment: `gplot <- gplot + geom_text(aes(15, 5, label=paste("Mean: ", my.mean)))`