# R ggplot2 - displaying values inside a histogram bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a data frame `df` and a column `col_name` I generate histograms like below.

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x=col_name)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                   binwidth=1,
                   colour="black", fill="white")
```

This gives me a histogram like below. I need to change two things in this.

1. display the density values at the top inside each bar
2. change the density value to percentage - instead of 0.4 , show 40%

[image: histogram]

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/ggplot2-how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot 

2. Use `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)` from the `scales` package.

Comment: Use stat_bin with geom = 'text'. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198896/how-to-get-data-labels-for-a-histogram-in-ggplot2